# ¿Por qué tengo que comprobar si un valor es NULL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

Tengo la consulta siguiente:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW muni_no_one_point_inside AS
SELECT 
      m.gid
    , scripts.stx_extract(m.geom, 2)
FROM muni m
LEFT JOIN LATERAL (
    SELECT ST_Collect(x.geom) as geom
    FROM (
        SELECT geom
        FROM munitextosmal mtm
        WHERE mtm.geom && m.geom
        AND ST_Relate(m.geom, mtm.geom, 'T********')
    )x
) as xx ON true
WHERE st_numGeometries(
    st_intersection(m.geom, xx.geom)
) <> 1
```

Es decir quiero obtener las geometrías que o **no intersecten con ningún punto (NULL)** o **que intersecten con más de un punto**.

Con la consulta anterior, los valores NULL no se cogen, tengo que forzar a que me coja los valores NULL, es decir, en la claúsula WHERE debo comprobar que el número de geometrías es NULL o distinto de 1.

```
WHERE st_numGeometries(
    st_intersection(m.geom, xx.geom)
)  IS NULL OR st_numGeometries(
    st_intersection(m.geom, xx.geom)
) <> 1
```

Mi pregunta es, ¿por qué no basta con comprobar que es distinto a 1?

¿Cómo internamente PostgreSQL decide que NULL no es distinto de  1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Postgres indica en su documentación que para comparar si un valor es NULL, esta comparación debe hacerse con IS NULL, ya que NULL en sí mismo es un valor indeterminado.
Incluso específica explícitamente que no se puede comparar con un NULL=NULL.

Parece que es la especificación oficial de SQL quien establece este comportamiento.
[Más información](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/functions-comparison.html)

Comment: Suponía que por ahí iban los tiros. Según la documentación, lo que puedo hacer es compararlo con IS DISTINCT FROM `numGeometrias IS DISTINTC FROM 1`. Mil gracias!! =)